# help with custom rewrite rules

Tags: rewrite-rules

I've inherited a site using Code Snippets plugin which has a snippet to rewrite URLs.

Unfortunately, I am not a developer so I am unsure what these do.

The problem we have is that in the Yoast SEO sitemap, the blog post URLs do not have a trailing slash. If you click on one of these links it redirects you to the URL with the trailing slash.

Ahrefs.com reports it is not a good idea to have 301 redirects in the sitemap.

If we disable the Code Snippets plugin, the problem goes away. I am pretty sure the snippet in question is:

```
function mandoe_blog_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $new_rules = array(
    '(([^/]+/)*blog)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',     
    'blog/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/[^/]+/embed/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/embed/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&embed=true',
    'blog/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&paged=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    'blog/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
//    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'blog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
  );
  $wp_rewrite->rules = array_merge($new_rules, $wp_rewrite->rules);
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'mandoe_blog_rewrite_rules' );

function mandoe_update_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
  $post = get_post( $id );
  if( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
    return home_url( '/blog/' . $post->post_name );
  }
  return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'mandoe_update_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

Can you please help identify which part of the code needs to be adjusted to add a trailing slash to blog posts?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that modifies the blog post URLs/permalinks is in the `mandoe_update_post_link()` function (which is hooked on [`post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/)), and the part that you need to adjust is this:

```php
return home_url( '/blog/' . $post->post_name );
```

Just change the `'/blog/' . $post->post_name` to `'/blog/' . $post->post_name . '/'` and the URLs would end with a slash. However, you may need to clear your site (and browser) caches in order for your sitemap to be using the new URL format, or for you to see the changes applied.

Comment: Perfect, you're a gem Sally